# match rownames and colnames of correlation matrix

Tags: r, grepl

I have a vector with 3990 names (these are the column names of my dataframe) and I want to match them with the rows of my data. My data contains correlation values and I want to subset my data based on the matches found

My data looks like this :
[image]

I tried using grepl

```
result <- filter(df, grepl(paste(column_names, collapse="|"), rownames(df)))
```

but I get an error

> error in 'grepl()': ! invalid regular expression

my expected output would be

[image]

does anyone have any suggestions on how can this be done?

would really be great if someone could help me with this!

Best,
Shweta

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide `dput(df)` fo your dataset.

Comment: try using `as.data.frame(as.table(df))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  filter(grepl(paste0("\\b", names(.), "\\b", collapse="|"), rownames(dat)))
          TATA TATB TATC TATD
TATA,TATA  0.8  0.2  0.5  0.1
TATB       0.2  0.9  0.4  0.5
TATA       0.9  0.4  0.2  0.1
```

Data:

```
dat <- data.frame(TATA = c(0.8,0.2,0.1,0.01,0.9),
                  TATB = c(0.2,0.9,0.2,0.4,0.4),
                  TATC = c(0.5,0.4,0.3,0.3,0.2),
                  TATD = c(0.1,0.5,0.15,0.5,0.1),
                  row.names = c("TATA,TATA", "TATB", "TATE", "TATM", "TATA"))
```

Comment: Hey @Chris, still getting the same error: Error in filter(., grepl(paste0("b", names(.), "b", collapse = "|"), : Caused by error in 'grepl()': ! invalid regular expression

Comment: You seem to have changed the code: `filter(., grepl(paste0("b", names(.), "b", collapse = "|")` is not the same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

Three options you can try:

```
library(reshape2)
melt(as.matrix(dat)
```

```
data.frame(rows=rownames(dat)[row(dat)], vars=colnames(dat)[col(dat)], values=c(dat))
```

```
as.data.frame(as.table(as.matrix(dat)))
```

result:

```
        Var1 Var2        Freq
1  TATA,TATA TATA 0.872624483
2       TATB TATA 0.533790730
3       TATE TATA 0.110495616
4       TATM TATA 0.253893718
5       TATA TATA 0.303576730
6  TATA,TATA TATB 0.774815753
7       TATB TATB 0.941361633
8       TATE TATB 0.305219935
9       TATM TATB 0.101124692
10      TATA TATB 0.968514156
11 TATA,TATA TATC 0.891697937
12      TATB TATC 0.006223573
13      TATE TATC 0.045138657
14      TATM TATC 0.848485971
15      TATA TATC 0.995542845
16 TATA,TATA TATD 0.479559761
17      TATB TATD 0.981808763
18      TATE TATD 0.227518091
19      TATM TATD 0.767491049
20      TATA TATD 0.410935185
```

data:

```
dat <- data.frame(TATA = runif(5),
                  TATB = runif(5),
                  TATC = runif(5),
                  TATD = runif(5),
                  row.names = c("TATA,TATA", "TATB", "TATE", "TATM", "TATA"))
```

EDIT:

Using regex matching to subset your input data, as a first step:

```
cols <- grep(pattern = paste0(rownames(dat), collapse = "|"), x = colnames(dat), value = TRUE)
rows <- grep(pattern = paste0(colnames(dat), collapse = "|"), x = rownames(dat), value = TRUE)

dat2 <- dat[rownames(dat) %in% rows, colnames(dat) %in% cols]
```

Yielding:

```
as.data.frame(as.table(as.matrix(dat2)))
       Var1 Var2      Freq
1 TATA,TATA TATA 0.6908219
2      TATB TATA 0.7255142
3      TATA TATA 0.1022963
4 TATA,TATA TATB 0.7291625
5      TATB TATB 0.7420069
6      TATA TATB 0.7480157
```

Comment: Hey @Skaqqs, I would like to match also the rownames and column names and only subset  dataframe based on the matches I would get

Comment: Hey. You could add this as a first step: `dat2 <- dat[rownames(dat) %in% colnames(dat), colnames(dat) %in% rownames(dat)]`

Comment: I added an edit to my answer that includes code to filter your input data using regex matching like you show in your question. Let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: Thanks, but with this I get an error

Comment: Error is : Error in grep(pattern = paste0(rownames(dat), collapse = "|"), x = colnames(dat), : 
  invalid regular expression

Comment: Are you using the example dataset from my answer? Note I'm using `dat` as the target dataframe name. If you run this on its own, it should be a character string: `paste0(rownames(dat), collapse = "|")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243618/discussion-between-shweta-godbole-and-skaqqs).